# PNY GeForce video cards

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I don't remember PNY making video cards, but then I noticed that there were some GeForce video cards that said PNY on them.  I thought NVidia made GeForce.  How good are those cards?  Why does the box say PNY if NVidia makes them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVidia make the GPU chips (and reference boards) other manufacturers put NVidia's chips on their boards. The same with AMD/ATI's graphics chips.

In this case PNY manufacture the boards using NVidia's GPUs.

Regarding how good the cards are, you'll need to go hunting reviews. The main difference between different manufacturer's cards using the same graphics chips tends to be the cooling arrangement, especially if the card is running the chip officially over-clocked.

Answer (score 1):

PNY is a board partner of nVidia just as BFG and Sapphire brands are. Pine Technologies (PNY) also owns the XFX performance-oriented brand.

Comment: oh gawd i had no idea.  no more XFX hardware for me, tyvm.